# Cannot revert .classpath and .project

Tags: classpath, project, workspace

I just created myself a new workspace by copying an existing one. I renamed the new one and deleted all included projects. Then i checked out some other projects. After this i got some local changes compared to the repository. These changes are in the .project and in the .classpath files.

The local .classpath looks like:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.cpcontainer.IVYDE_CONTAINER/?project=project&amp;ivyXmlPath=ivy.xml&amp;confs=*"/>
```

and on the remote repository it looks like:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.cpcontainer.IVYDE_CONTAINER/?ivyXmlPath=ivy.xml&amp;confs=*"/>
```

The local .project looks like:

```
<nature>org.apache.ivyde.eclipse.ivynature</nature>
```

and in the remote repository this nature does not even exist.

If i revert these changes, SpringToolSuite instantly makes these changes again. Can someone tell me how i can fix this?